# Highlight cell border with TreeListView in ObjectListView

Tags: objectlistview

When I click on a cell in TreeListView I want the border of the cell to be highlighted.

Is this possible?

I can only find the highlight background and foreground options.

Thanks

Comment: Border around the cell or the whole line?

Comment: border around the cell

Comment: This could get complicated. You would probably have to use the `CellClick` event and adjust the `CellBorderDecoration` property of the respective item. But this could yield some issues with refreshing. I haven't done it yet and have no time to look into it at the moment.

Comment: Thanks I might leave it for simplicity.